# open pbix file if not opened in VBA

Tags: vba, shell, powerbi

I am trying to open a Power Bi desktop ".pbix" file from VBA if the file is not opened already. All I am looking for is a way to launch power bi desktop

```
Shell("notepad.exe " & myDirectory, vbNormalFocus)
```

Can someone please provide me a string which can sub 'notepad.exe' with something which works for power bi
I tried "Powerbi" and "PowerbiDesktop" with and without spacings but nothing works for me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***All I am looking for is a way to launch power bi desktop***

Find the application and right click to get the target address. Use that target address and query winmgmts to ensure process not already running.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    If GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='PBIDesktop.exe'").Count = 0 Then
        Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\PBIDesktop.exe", vbNormalFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

> ***I am trying to open a Power Bi desktop ".pbix" file from VBA if the file is not opened already.***

For specific PBI file:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = "C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\NEL VTE Template SQL.pbix"

    If Not IsFileOpen(fileName) Then
        Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\PBIDesktop.exe" & " " & """" & fileName & """"
    End If

End Sub

'Adapted by me from https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-find-file-already-open/
Public Function IsFileOpen(ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim errNum As Long

    'Allow all errors to happen
    On Error Resume Next
    fileNum = FreeFile()

    'Try to open and close the file for input.
    'Errors mean the file is already open
    Open fileName For Input Lock Read As #fileNum
    Close fileNum

    'Get the error number
    errNum = Err

    'Do not allow errors to happen
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Check the Error Number
    Select Case errNum

        'errNum = 0 means no errors, therefore file closed
    Case 0
        IsFileOpen = False

        'errNum = 70 means the file is already open
    Case 70
        IsFileOpen = True

        'Something else went wrong
    Case Else
        IsFileOpen = errNum

    End Select

End Function
```

Ref:

1. [Determine if application is running with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807691/determine-if-application-is-running-with-excel)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39903527/6241235  @Tony Emrud